# jquery UI slider rotate

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, jquery-ui

I am using [jquery-ui's slider](http://jqueryui.com/slider/), as `input[type=range]` looks dissimilar in all browsers and there is no way to make it look exactly the same across browsers (my target audience is using all latest browsers).

Now I have multiple jQuery-ui sliders in a page. I want to rotate them using CSS3, to create a custom complex control (which requires uniform look-and-feel of range/slider control). Here is what I have so far:

HTML:

```
<div class="slider"></div>
<div class="slider"></div>
<div class="slider"></div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$('.slider').slider({
    min: 1, max: 10, step: 1
});
```

CSS:

```
.slider:last-of-type {
    transform: rotate(150deg); /* you can try with 180deg to see a clear difference */
}
```

It rotates well, but its behavior is inversed: *When we click on the one end of the scroller, it moves the knob to the oppose end.*

I tried rotating the `input[type=range]` as well, and it doesn't exhibit this problem.

- Is there a quick way to fix this issue in jQuery-UI slider?

(if not)

- Is there any other library, which offers the similar range control with uniform look-and-feel across (latest) browsers?